# How does magento2 associates an entity with it's table?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, database, magento2.2

How does magento2 connects an entity with it's table ?
For example if in `\Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer` we do `$this->getEntityTable()`. We get the table name *customer_entity*. 
Where is this set ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table is buried in the database in the table eav_entity_type. The field `entity_table` in this table has the table for the entity.

to follow the process through, go for instance in the Customer Resource Model and lookup the __construct method: within this function the entity type is set: `$this->setType('customer')`.

And then this function will lead to the function `\Magento\Eav\Model\Config::getEntityType`

the below is where the database info are assigned to the Resource Model

```
$entityType = $this->_entityTypeFactory->create(
    ['data' => isset($this->_entityTypeData[$code]) ? $this->_entityTypeData[$code] : []]
 );
```